# Loading OpenGL > 1.1 functions Windows

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I'm having trouble setting up OpenGL with MSVS 2013. I'm aware that the **opengl32.dll** on my Windows
platform located at `C:\Windows\System32` is an implementation of OpenGL 1.1.

What I'm trying to do is to load the newer OpenGL > 1.1 functions such as `glBindBuffer` and `glBufferData`. I have read that it's possible getting a pointer to the function using `wglGetProcAddress`. When using this function the returned pointer is always null, all the original functions in the dll using `GetProcAddress(OpenGL32DLL, "...")` work perfectly except the newer functions don't seem to load.

I'm hoping anybody here can help me go through my setup and point out what I did wrong or if I have missed something.

So here we go:

- I have downloaded OpenGL Extensions Viewer 4.4 which points out I'm able to perfectly run upto OpenGL 2.1 which
  should be more than enough to use or load `glBindBuffer` and `glBufferData`.
- I downloaded Microsoft SDKs/v7.1 which includes the headers: `gl/glu.h` and `gl/gl.h`; I also downloaded the GLEXT extensions API
  from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/glextwin32/) and linked the `glext.lib` + included the headers.
- Files in the Linker:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\OpenGL32.Lib
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\GlU32.Lib
>
> C:\Users\user\Desktop\glext\lib\glext.lib

- The CPP files included:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Include -> GL.h, GLU.h
>
> C:\Users\user\Desktop\glext\include -> glcorearb.h, glext.h, wglext.h

Comment: Have you created an OpenGL context before calling `wglGetProcAddress`?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of handling all these details yourself, I suggest you just grab yourself a copy of GLEW ( http://glew.sourceforge.net/ ) which handles all of this for you in a standard way.  I currently use it on several published products without issues.

In your example, you'd be able to do the following:

```
if (GL_ARB_multi_bind) {
    //glBindBuffer is available.
}
```

(Of course, after a call to `glewInit()`, possibly with `glewExperimental = TRUE;` - see documentation for details.)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. I'm aware about the glew library but i would love to do this without it since this is only a very small part of a bigger project, i want to keep everything as lightweight as possible.

Comment: @MircoProgram Honestly, it's a header-only solution, so you wouldn't be affecting much in terms of performance, compile time or binary size. You will ensure you are doing things correctly, and adding functionality will be trivial.

Comment: @MikeWeir: GLEW is *not* a "header-only" library (not unless something changed recently). Now, GLEW is not a heavy-weight component either, so there's still no legitimate reason *not* to use it or another loading library.

Comment: @NicolBolas I can believe you when you say it's not header-only, but could you please indicate why you feel it can't be described as such? Definition taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header-only seems to be accurate.  As far as I'm aware, I only include header files in projects where I use this library.

Comment: @MikeWeir: GLEW builds a compiled library file, a .lib or .o or whatever. You cannot use GLEW without including this file.

Comment: @NicolBolas You are right, my bad :P. But yeah, it's pretty lightweight :P.

Answer (score 1):

> When using this function the returned pointer is always null, all the original functions in the dll using GetProcAddress(OpenGL32DLL, "...") work perfectly except the newer functions don't seem to load.

Do you have a valid OpenGL context created and made current on the calling thread? In Windows extension functions are technically per-context, i.e. you have to get the pointers to the functions for each OpenGL context you create and make sure to use the right function pointers with the right context.

This of course also means that you must have a OpenGL context to begin with. The usual sequence of setting up an OpenGL context in Windows is:

pseudocode

```
struct glctx {
    HGLRC rc
    // dictionary for explanation purposes
    // one would normally just have a bunch of
    // structure elements here
    functionpointer[string:name] extensionfunction
}

if not window_with_desired_pixelformat_exists: {
    wnd := create_a_window
    pixelformat := select_pixelformat
    wnd→set_pixelformat pixelformat
}
dc := wnd→getDC

glctx ctx
ctx→rc := wglCreateContext(dc)
wglMakeCurrent(dc, ctx→rc);

foreach(fname in extensionfunctions_names): {
    ctx→extensionfunction[name] = wglGetProcAddress(name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that there is no current context while calling wglGetProcAddress.

Function pointers can be specific for a precise pixel format, determined by tge context creation procedure.